# Why the letter "g" discrepancy between *giant* and *gigantic*?

Tags: etymology, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

A little look through an etymology dictionary shows that the root is Latin *gigas* with adjective form *gigant*.  So in its derivation to English, why did the second "g" get retained in *gigantic* but was dropped from *giant*?

I have an inkling that the word *giant* may have travelled through French on its way to English, where it may have been pronounced "gee-yant" or "jee-yant" with a change to the second "g" that was then dropped when taken into English.  However, the "g" is retained as a hard "g" in gigantic.

Comment: A correction: the root of the word is Greek, not Latin. It was adopted by the Romans, like the rest of the Greek mythology. When it passed to Old French it was probably changed from "gigas" to "geant". It was only the adjective that kept the original "g" in French, too.

Comment: @Irene: Any references?

Comment: @Kris: Yes. "etymonline.com" for the etymology of the word and "wordreference.com" (English-French dictionary). Sorry for not giving you direct links, but I haven't found out how to do that yet.

Comment: @Irene: Thanks all the same, the domain name references are fine enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word *gigantic* comes to English relatively recently. *Giant*, as you probably know if you've investigated the etymology, appears in Middle English by way of Old French *geant* [NOAD]. *Gigantic*, on the other hand, appears first in Modern English [in the 16th or 17th century](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gigantic&allowed_in_frame=0), three or four hundred years later. The reference at that time was probably to the original Latin (via Greek) *gigas*.

Comment: What I'm taking from this is, the two words, though similar, took seperate routes from Latin to English.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Wade.  Yes.  There are many other cases with odder results, such as *shirt* and *skirt* from the same Germanic root meaning *short*.

Comment: Yes, that's a good one. _Shirt_ is the original AS word, which got palatalized before the Norse invasions; _skirt_ is the Norse version, which never got palatalized because it was in Norway instead of England.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Actually, the original AS (OE) word was *scyrte*. The *sc* would have been pronounced the way we pronounce *sh* today.

Comment: Sorry, should've been clearer. "_Shirt_ is **the ModE cognate of** the original AS word". And _scyrte_ would at one point -- **pre-** palatalization -- have been pronounced /skirte/ or /skürte/.

Comment: You can see an interesting effect of the different ages of loans into English with this root: "giant" shows the French loss of intervocalic "g"; "gigantic" is a learned form from French, so it retains the second "g" but the first one takes the typical French-influenced palatalized  /dʒ/ sound, and the prefix "giga-" taken from the Greek root is now fashionably pronounced /gɪgə/ in English with an unpalatalized g, as if adapted directly from the Greek. (Or more to the point, from the spelling.)

Comment: The word *gigantic* replaced the earlier *gigantine* in English; *gigantine* was borrowed from French (the current French word is *gigantesque*). Presumably the reason that *gigantine* was replaced by *gigantic* in English was that scholars preferred it because it was closer to the original Greek *gigantikos*. I have no idea why *gigantesque* replaced *gigantine* in French. But either way, the reason the second *g* was dropped from the noun but not the adjective is that this is what happened in French.

Answer (score 7):

One of those occasionally (but never perfectly) useful pronunciation rules for English spellings (which was not designed -- to be fair -- to represent **Modern** English pronunciation, but rather **Middle** English, quite a different-sounding language) is that ***C*** or ***G*** before ***I*** or ***E*** often get pronounced /s/ or /ʃ/ or /tʃ/ (for ***C***), and /ʒ/ or /dʒ/ (for ***G***).

This is a result of several historic bouts of ***[Palatalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization)*** in both English and the Romance languages (notably French, which supplied loads of English words, and Italian, which supplied Latin words in the form of [Church Latin](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LatinPronunciation.pdf), quite a different-sounding language from Classical Latin).

As the Wikipedia article points out, sounds around the palatal region (alveolars like /*t*/, /*d*/, and /*s*/, and velars like /*k*/ and /*ɡ*/), tend to "migrate" toward the palatal region in anticipation whenever the tongue moves toward that region, which is where tense front vowels (like /*i*/ and /*e*/) are produced (by the tongue, that is; other organs are also involved). It's a natural reflex, and is unavoidable at normal speech speeds. Everybody does it. So migration is more or less  constant, though at different rates.

Of course, ***I*** and ***E*** [are no longer pronounced](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2VowelShifts.pdf) /*i*/ and /*e*/ in Modern English, but the palatalization they wrought while they were both high front vowels lives after them.

That's all, really. Welcome to the wonderful world of English orthography. There's all these fossils lying around, which is fascinating for us paleontologists, but frustrating for tourists, who keep tripping over them.

Comment: I don't get it. What does that say about 'giant' and 'gigantic' in particular? Are you saying there was a sound change in the first 'g's -after- they were borrowed from French (for 'giant') or created out of Latin (for 'gigantic')?

Comment: I'm saying that the G in _giant_ and the **first** G in _gigantic_ come before I, and are therefore pronounced like J, but the **second** G in _gigantic_ isn't because it comes before A, and not before I or E. And I'm saying the reason for this is that English sounds changed, but English didn't change its spelling.

Comment: @JohnLawler True enough but I don't think this is what the question is asking.  The question is asking why we have the word "giant" instead of "gigant", but "gigantic" instead of "giantic".

Comment: And the answer is that those were the wordforms that were borrowed from Greek and other languages. If you would like an explanation of why precisely **those** wordforms were borrowed and not others, you may apply for a grant to build a time machine and conduct a sociolinguistic survey over a millennium.

Comment: The OED says that *gigantic* replaced *gigantine* in English, *gigantine* having been borrowed from French. Presumably this happened because scholars thought they should use words closer to the original Greek: gigantikos.